Banno Icon configuration for alerts/messages
Does the Banno platform allow the delivery icons to be configurable in any way?
We would like to send push notifications with an envelope icon as opposed to the exclamation icon but it doesn't look like this is configurable in any way.
Push notifications were received but appeared with the exclamation icon as opposed to envelope icon.

For clarity, which endpoint are you referring to in the API?

Hi Sam,
Thanks for the response.  The endpoint I'm referring to is:
/a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/alert/send/generic
